# My MC Launcher Starts, But When I Press Play Nothing Happens. (Mods)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I have DrZhark's MoCreatures v6.2.1 and CustomMobSpawner 3.2.0 in my "mods" folder in .minecraft.

Obviously Vanilla works, just not my mods. I followed many tutorials and did exactly what I was supposed to do. Maybe I have the wrong Java?

I installed Forge and I created a new profile. For the "Use Version" I selected `release 1.7.2-Forge10.12.2.1161-mc172`

The forge installer version is: forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.1161-mc172-installer

I am running Windows 8.1. Is that why there's a problem?

For "Executable": `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe`

For JVM Arguments: `-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't write up a full answer right now, but I will later if no one beats me to it: you need to downgrade your Java to 1.7, there's a bug in Java 1.8 that breaks Forge somehow. There was a news post about it on the Technic site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support for modded Minecraft**](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Forge does not act well with Java 8u20+, you need to throw this mod in your mods folder, it should fix everything : http://files.minecraftforge.net/LegacyJavaFixer/legacyjavafixer-1.0.jar
It was created by LexManos to fix this issue and its license is the MIT License.

Other solutions :

- Downgrade your Java
- Use a more recent version of Forge/FML, this issue seems to be fixed (see https://github.com/LexManos/LegacyJavaFixer/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: That's actually very useful! Thanks for information.

Comment: so i downloaded it, and i can get onto minecraft now. Thank you!

Comment: Except, (IP) CreatureCraft.Us wont work, there is an X that says: Incompatible FML modded server 5 mods present. When i join the server it says: Connection Lost Mod rejections [FMLMod:CustomSpawner{3.2.0},FMLMod:MoCreatures{6.2.1}]    Can anyone help me with this? Nothing has changed except that mod you told me to throw in. Well, i'm not sure if the mods are different. before i put forge inside the mods folder and did not have custom mob spawner. I will check tomorrow night, when i get my old computer back, and see what versions i used. I used optifine and voxelmaps before. Not using them atm.

Comment: So i tried another MoC server, and that was the correct version. It said it had connection, but when i join the server it stops responding then says: Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException   I need to fix this, and i just can't find out how to do it. At the moment i am downloading jre-7-windows-x64.exe.

Comment: For CreatureCraft you may not have the right version of the mods. For the ReadTImeoutException, it might be your firewall blocking the server or your internet connection that is not stable

Comment: there is only one download to the mods on the official MoC website. Where could i get the proper version thats not a virus?

Comment: okay, thank you! i got a friend to send me the right files. haven't downloaded them, but i'm sure they'll work. Also, i managed to get on the server afterwards.

Comment: gah. i still cant get the right files for Creature craft!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to downgrade java if you installed an jre1.8.0.19 or older, you just need to insert 
in executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\version\bin\javaw.exe